# Android wear action item icon sizing vs phone notification action item sizing

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm a little confused about what size an icon should be for my application's notification action items.  I want to make the action items compatible for Android wear, but there is no documentation (that I can find) on what size to make the icons.

Looking at sample android wear projects, I see that the icon sizes for the android wear action items are 64dp x 64dp (for instance, reply).  Looking from google source examples, I'm seeing that icon sizes for action items on phones match those of the action bar, with 32dp x 32dp size and a 24dp x 24dp optical square, also specified [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#action-bar).

When I keep the icons at 32x32, they look terrible on the android wear device, and when I keep them as 64x64, they are too large for the action item bar on the phone.

Is there a way (different res folder? using the WearableExtender?) to have the phone use a different icon for action items than the wearable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the actions once again using the `WearableExtender` class. It will allow you to set a set of actions that will be visible only on Android Wear device (the original actions added to `NotificationCompat.Builder` will not be visible if you set at least one action via `WearableExtender`. So basically you just need to "repeat" all the actions in `WearableExtender` and specify different (bigger) icons there.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.reply_phone, "Reply", pendingIntent));
builder.extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
            .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.reply_wear, "Reply", pendingIntent))
        );
```

Comment: No..? Can you show your code and results that you only have one action on Android Wear?

Comment: My bad, I solved my bug.  Thanks for calling me out so I second guessed myself.  I was instantiating a new WearableExtender() every time I was adding an action, so they were just overriding each other.  I'm going to delete my previous comment in a couple of days so I don't mislead people.